# How to do type casting for the below expression

Tags: c, string, error-handling, realloc

I am trying to reallocate memory to my table using the below expression.But I always keep getting the below error.Please kindly advise me.

```
typedef char *OFAttribs[6];
 OFAttribs *tmp = realloc(pTable, sizeof(*tmp) * (nTableLen+1));

Error: invalid conversion from âvoid*â to âchar* (*)[6]â
```

Comment: You typedef'd a pointer to an array. And arrays are in essence pointers too. So your type is a pointer to a pointer. Then you declared a pointer to that type. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @AE: Arrays are *not* pointers, and the `OFAttribs` type here is most definitely *not* a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @caf If you try compiling `int a[2]; int b = a;` as C++ you will get the following error from gcc `invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'`. So in this case 'a' is indeed a pointer to int.

Comment: @AE: In an expression where it is not the subject of either unary `&` or `sizeof`, an array *evaluates to* a pointer to its first element, but that is not what it *is*.  You can see this if you change it to `int b = &a;` - the error will say invalid conversion from `int (*)[2]`, *not* `int **`.  This shows that the actual type of `a` is `int [2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
OFAttribs *tmp = (OFAttribs*) realloc(pTable, sizeof(*tmp) * (nTableLen+1));
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you've shown is valid C.  Are you sure you aren't mistakenly compiling in C++ mode, where `void *` is not implicitly convertible to other pointer types?